# Calculate pixel generated via rate and display size

Tags: graphics

Consider 2 raster systems with resolution 640X480 and 1280X1024. How many pixels could be accessed per second in each of these systems by display controller that refreshes screen at rates of 60 frames per second. What is access time per pixel  in each system?

Please explain in details

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly. To me it looks as simple as `width * height * rate = pixels_per_second` and `1 / pixels_per_second = seconds_per_pixel`. If so, then I have no idea what explanations you may need.

Comment: It was actually asked on the final exam Paper of Engineering and I posted exactly not finding the answer